# Redux toolkit serializableMiddleware doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, redux, middleware, redux-toolkit

I encountered with an issue of serializableMiddleware in redux toolkit. I need to store firestore timestamps inside my redux store and don't want that serializableMiddleware logged this text:

> A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `path to timestamp`. Value: nt {seconds: > 1675422816, nanoseconds: 106000000}
> Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this action.

So i take a look at the serializableMiddleware in redux toolkit docs and find out that there is an option `isSerializable?: (value: any) => boolean`. When I return true from this method, value should consider serializable, but still logs error out even if I always return true.

I wrote function but it didn't work:

```
const isSerializable = (value: any) => 
    value instanceof Timestamp || isPlain(value);

const serializableMiddleware = createSerializableStateInvariantMiddleware({
    isSerializable
})
```

Here is how I setup my store:

```
export const setupStore = () => {
    return configureStore({ 
        reducer: rootReducer,
        middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
            getDefaultMiddleware()
            .concat(serializableMiddleware)
    })
}
```

Comment: How are you adding that `serializableMiddleware` to the store?  Normally, if you need to alter the settings, you should be calling `getDefaultMiddleware()` and customizing its fields as shown here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#customizing-the-included-middleware

Comment: @markerikson I edited my post with sample of how I add this middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that [`getDefaultMiddleware()` *already* adds the serializable middleware as part of the default setup](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#included-default-middleware).  You're creating a *second* instance of the middleware, but that doesn't change the *first* instance.

Instead, you need to customize the first instance by passing the right options to `getDefaultMiddleware()`:

```
export const setupStore = () => {
    return configureStore({ 
        reducer: rootReducer,
        middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
            getDefaultMiddleware({
             serializableCheck: {
               isSerializable: myCustomIsSerializableFunction
             }
            })
    })
}
```